# binded data tables for leaflet maps in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, leaflet

I want to bind a leaflet map to a according datatable using django. I've just googled it and not sure if I've used the correct buzz words.
At the end I want to interact in a first shot, so that:

1. clicking on the data table element zooms to leaflet map feature and
2. the bounds of displayed features on maps - filters the data table

For displaying the features  on the map, I'm using geojson.
What are the best practises for that use case?

my map.js handler

```
const attribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
const map = L.map('map', {
    center: [52.39886, 13.06566],
    zoom: 10
});
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: attribution }).addTo(map);
const markers = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('markers-data').textContent);
let feature = L.geoJSON(markers, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

        if(feature.properties.kategorie == 1){
            layer.setStyle({color :'black'});
        } else {

        }

        layer.bindPopup('<strong>Parkname: </strong>'+layer.feature.properties.name.toString() +
        '<br /> <strong>Kategorie: </strong>' + layer.feature.properties.kategorie.toString());

    }
}).addTo(map)
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
import logging
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from .models import NotusProjekte
from django.db.models import Q

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MarkersMapView(TemplateView):
    """Markers map view."""

    template_name = "map.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Return the view context data."""
        query = NotusProjekte.objects.using('spatial').filter(Q(kategorie=1) | Q(kategorie=2))
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["markers"] = json.loads(serialize("geojson", query))
        logger.debug(context["markers"])
        return context
```